# Power 3 V or 5 V device only when AC device (induction plate) consumes power

Tags: power-supply, arduino, induction

I have a 5 V circuit with an Arduino using a current sensor (ZMCT103C) to monitor when an induction plate is in use, and then power on the ventilation (range hood).

The 5 V circuit is powered by an AC-DC power source, and is consuming power all the time.

Is there any solution to power on the AC-DC power source only when the plate is in use?
It's not consuming that much power, but it adds up over time, since the circuit acts only once every few days.

Ideally I would want to only consume power (power on the Arduino) when the plate is used, without having to alter the plate.

Comment: You could perhaps use a current transformer to activate a relay.

Comment: @user253751 Good hint, I found [AC Current Sensing Switch Using Current Transformer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/335570/ac-current-sensing-switch-using-current-transformer)

Comment: Right, and if done well, you should be able to directly activate a relay using the power siphoned from the current transformer, without even needing a microcontroller